# How does a Broker-Dealer lend shares to other Broker-Dealers?

Tags: market-data, market-microstructure, market-making, short-selling

Is it possible to find out how a OTC Broker-Dealer in thinly-traded equities lends shares for short-sales to other Broker-Dealers. Which platform or process is involved?

Comment: This is a highly specialized subject and not my area of expertise. I understand that the broker would delegate the details to a Lending Agent, often a bank such as BNY Mellon or JP Morgan Chase that would handle the day to day administration of the lending program and serve as an intermediary to the borrowers.

Comment: @AlexC is there a repo market for this?

Comment: I wonder if it would make sense that Broker-Dealers buy CALL options for hard-to-borrow securities to cover there short positions from other brokers?